# get multiple checkbox value with select all and update value into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

hello friends i m trying to make a inbox system in which we select all checkbox with the help of one checkbox and then through ajax pass the value to all checkbox and update the database. but the problem is that they values and being selected one by one and then forming a array

for eg

fst time 2
second time 2,3
third time 2,3,4

and at the sql query where i am trying to get the list of array and break them so that i can update the value in database its also not happening , can anyone help ?here is what i coded.

to get the value of checkbox

```
           $(function(){
   $('.massmsgdelbutton').click(function(){
    var val = [];
  $('.sltchk:checked').each(function(i){
   val[i] = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'massmsgdel='+ val;
  if(confirm("Sure you want move all these messages to Trash? There is NO undo!"))
  {

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "modules/messages/sql_ex.php",
data: dataString,
 cache: false,

 success: function(html){
 alert(html);
  }
 });

  }

});
 });
});
```

my sql code using expode to explode the array

```
       if(isset($_REQUEST['massmsgdel']))
         {
     $id=$_REQUEST['massmsgdel'];
        $myArray[] = explode(',', $id);
     echo $id;
        $sql=mysql_query("update message set trash='1' where message_id='$myArray'");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys i found the solution .

in the jquery i had to use

```
  var dataString = 'massmsgdel='+ val[i];
```

instead of

```
  var dataString = 'massmsgdel='+ val;
```

and in sql i had to use

```
      $sql=mysql_query("update message set trash='1' where message_id IN ('$myArray')");
```

thanks @Frank Allenby for helping me the way out

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are really two approaches you can use here. From my experience, anyway.

You can either loop through the array(foreach loop) you have and perform an UPDATE each time, something like the following:

```
$sql=mysql_query("update message set trash='1' where message_id='$messageID'");
```

Or you could try using the IN SQL Operator(which you can find more info on [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)), something like so:

```
$sql=mysql_query("update message set trash='1' where message_id IN ('$messageID1', '$messageID2', '$messageID3', '$messageID4')");
```

The IN Operator will match the message_id to any of the parameters in the parenthesis.

Comment: but the result is in array  and its not coming in echo also i think there is something wrong with my jquery

Comment: Well, in your case you would substitute "messageID1", etc. for "myArray[0]", etc. in order to use the values in your query. I'm not sure about the JQuery, as I'm not too clued up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work?

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['massmsgdel']))
{
     $id=$_REQUEST['massmsgdel'];
        $myString = implode(',', $id);
     echo $id;
        $sql=mysql_query("update message set trash='1' where message_id IN ($myString)");
}
```

Comment: ohh sorry then. i guess, implode should work. anyway, waiting for correct answer.